# JSON file parsing using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON file with such detailes in it(not full file):

```
{"property": [
    {

 {
      "name": "test1",
      "value": "{\"test_type\":\"jsystem\",\"order\":1,\"test_id\":\"test_01\",\"physical_setup_id\":\"prd_01\",\"timeout\":\"20\"}",
      "own": true
    },
   {
      "name": "test2",
      "value": "{\"test_type\":\"jsystem\",\"order\":2,\"test_id\":\"test_02\",\"physical_setup_id\":\"prd_02\",\"timeout\":\"30\"}",
      "own": true
    },
   {
      "name": "pass",
      "value": "{\"test_type\":\"jsystem\",\"order\":3,\"test_id\":\"test_03\",\"physical_setup_id\":\"prd_01\",\"timeout\":\"15\"}",
      "own": true
    }
 ]
}
```

And I am trying to extract all the fields that are contain "name test%NUMBER%" 
I've tried this:
`cat build.json | jq '.property | .[] | select(.name=="test1")'`  - it works OK , but I want to add digital parameter to .name==test.
Something like this:

```
cat build.json | jq '.property | .[] | select(.name=="test'[0-9]'")'
```

Ans second I need to parse each data under "value" parameter.
Like this:

```
test1:
test_type=jsystem
order=1
test_id=test_01


]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "digital parameter"? and could you please post the code you are using? Thanks

Comment: Hi! I meant - that "test1" "test2" "test3" it could be any number after word "test". The code I've wrote above: cat build.json | jq '.property | .[] | select(.name=="test1")'

Comment: A complete example JSON object would be helpful.  I don't even see a `.property`.

Comment: Please see updated question - properties are added

Comment: The json is broken if it uses strings for sub-dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

With jq 1.5, regular expression support has been added

So assuming `property` is an array of your test objects (your example is broken and invalid), you could do this to select the objects with names that follow the pattern:

```
.property | map(select(.name | test("test[0-9]")))
```

Then for each of those objects, the `value` appears to be json strings.  You would have to parse those out before you could get anything out of those.

```
.property | map(
    select(.name | test("test[0-9]"))
        | .value |= fromjson
        | { name } + .value
    )
```

This will give you an array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "test_type": "jsystem",
    "order": 1,
    "test_id": "test_01",
    "physical_setup_id": "prd_01",
    "timeout": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "test_type": "jsystem",
    "order": 2,
    "test_id": "test_02",
    "physical_setup_id": "prd_02",
    "timeout": "30"
  }
]
```

Format it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks! You've saved my day!

Comment: One more thing...How can I split the result to something like this